# how to create one input text and save the result to separated fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a question. how to create one input text and fill it with this format:   
, then save the result to database with separated fields:
- name
- age
- address
like example input : "Rangga Lawe 22 Jl Soekarno Jakarta" 
so, it will save to database as follows:
- “Rangga Lawe“ to `name` field
- “22” to `age` field
- “Jl Soekarno Jakarta” to `address` field
please help me, thankyou.

im using mongoDb as my database and use node.js framework

Comment: I do not recommend this. I can think of no certain method how to split user generated content like your's to separate fields. Just imagine: User does not give his age, Name has a number in it, Address has numbers in it. How will you know, at which place to separate? Either use separate input fields or store the whole string as one. Maybe you will find people, who are willing to split the data in your database into meaningful fields and like to edit those. It's a tedious work

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the value on the basis of some parameters. like instruct the user to input comma separated  values. OR 
You have to make input field fixed length for each of your values..

Answer (score 0):

if you only have one input means that you have only one string that you want to parse into an array and then insert this fields into your database.
like this:

```
var str = "Rangga Lawe 22 Jl Soekarno Jakarta";
var result = str.split(" ");
//now you can work with the array
//console.log(result[0]) will contain "Rangga"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the one input into multiple ones at the Schema level if you use Mongoose ORM for your mongoDB database using the .pre middleware.

Here is an example :

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const user = this
    const data = user.fieldYouWantToSplit.split(" ")
    user.address = data[0]
    user.number = data[1]
    return next()
})
```

})

Comment: and how to call it into html as an input text?